# Configuration of views with entity reference fields

Tags: entities, views

I've read several guides about this subject but still incapable of achieving what I want.

I have a main content type (aventuras) and then another content type for images. The images are referenced to the main content type via an Entity Reference field.

I want to create a view that shows a list of all the nodes of the main content type (their titles and other fields) along with their images (reference field).

I think I need to add the "Entity Reference: Referenced Entity" relationship and then the image field with that relationship selected, but that is not working (it only shows fields of the main content type, no image).

I've tried several alternatives (contextual filters, adding also the relationship to the filter, using Referencing Entity instead of Referenced...) without any luck.

Maybe this is an annoying noobie question that has been answered before, but I've searched and tried a lot and I can't find the solution for my case.

Any clue would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The images are referenced to the main content type via an Entity
>   Reference field.

Who has the entity reference field? The Main content type (aventuras)?  OR the Images content type?

Based on your question, I will guess the Main content type.

If the Main content type has the entity reference field, then **under Advanced** you need to add a relationship of Referec**ing** and NOT Referenc**ed** Entity (notice the bold endings).

Also, no need to add a relationship in the image field.